# QextSerialPort::read() does not return until timeout expired but data is available

Tags: windows, qt, qextserialport

I am using QextSerialPort with Qt 4.8.1 on Win32.  When "polling" query mode is set, and a timeout set using QextSerialPort::setTimeout().  When I call QExtSerialPort::read(), even when data is available, the read function does not return until the entire timeout period has expired, even though it returns with data.

For example:

```
m_port->setTimeout( 3000 ) ;
char data = 0 ;
int count = m_port->read( &data, 1 ) ;
// Returns after three seconds, but count is 1, and data set as expected
```

I would expect it to return as soon a the specified number or bytes are read *or* the timeout expires - which ever occurs first.

Should this work or am I misunderstanding this interface?  Is there a way of achieving the expected behaviour in polling mode.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the solution is to open in unbuffered mode thus:

```
m_port->open( QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Unbuffered ) ;
```

I am not really sure why that should be necessary, so if anyone can shed some light on the philosophy of this interface design I'd still be interested in any answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure QExtSerial uses ReadFile() on Windows.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx

Is there an error string returned? qextserialport->errorString();

Maybe ReadFile() is getting hung up but not until it has already pushed data into the pointer?

Answer (score 0):

I think, problem is in `QIODevice::read(char *data, qint64 maxSize)` **function** from **qiodevice.cpp** file:

```
qint64 QIODevice::read(char *data, qint64 maxSize)
{
    ...
            if ((d->openMode & Unbuffered) == 0 && maxSize < QIODEVICE_BUFFERSIZE) {
                ...
                int bytesToBuffer = QIODEVICE_BUFFERSIZE;
                ...
                qint64 readFromDevice = readData(writePointer, bytesToBuffer);
                ...
            }
    ...
}
```

where `QIODEVICE_BUFFERSIZE` is **16384**.

`readData()` function is implemented in **QextSerialPort** and calls `ReadFile() WinApi` function.

Comment: What is your point? How would someone having this problem use this information to fix it?

Comment: I can drill into the source code too - that does not really help though. The implementation should abstract from the native API to provide the defined interface across all platforms. I have of course since worked around the problem, and have not recently updated the library to determine whether it has since been resolved - that project has shipped already..